# Why the JDK Version in MANIFEST.MF and class file is different

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, java-8, java-7

I built my project(JDK version 1.7) with Jenkins (version 2.164.1 with JDK 1.8)

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

then I got a jar file,
when I unzip the jar file and vim the MANIFEST.MF

```
Build-Jdk:1.8.0_131
```

then I run

```
javap -verbose MyClass.class | grep "major"
major version: 51
```

the class file JDK version is 1.7

My project need to run with JDK1.7,is there a trouble with this?

Comment: it says that the build jdk that was used is `1.8`, but the `51` tells you that "it's" `1.7` - you are OK. what is your concern here?

Comment: I am worried that my project is finally compiled with JDK1.8, but the runtime is JDK1.7, there will be problems.

Comment: generally - no, you should be just fine, you do specify `source/target` to be `1.7` after all.

Comment: You also have to make sure to not use any API introduced in JDK8. You should get the rt.jar from JDK7 and set the bootclasspath to point at it. (Or to be safe, just compile with JDK7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add Eugene's comment:

`Build-Jdk` tells you the exact version of the JDK that you used to compile (in your case, this is the 1.8.0_131). This JDK can build code with various compatibility levels. These levels are configured in the maven-compiler-plugin. So you build a Java 1.7 compatible code with Java 1.8, which is probably exactly what you want.

You may ask what the `Build-Jdk` version is for: It helps to you to track down problems that might come from bugs in the JDK or other incompatibilities.

Comment: I understand, but I have a concern. I have been compiling with JDK1.7 before. Now if I use JDK1.8 to compile a 1.7 project, will there be a problem at runtime in JDK1.7? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Most probably not. Nobody can say there are no bugs, but it is unlikely.